# Install MS Fonts for xvfb-run in Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: server, 14.04, xorg, fonts, xvfb

I have a cron which runs and takes a screenshot of a specific url. The job is:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" /usr/bin/cutycapt 
--min-width=1200 --min-height=1200 --delay=1000 
--url=http://themer.mydomain.co.uk/_sh.php?id=1 
--out=/home/www/mydomain/co.uk/themer/1.png
```

This runs and stores the screenshot fine, and when using webfonts provided from Google they load properly.

But when we are using fonts from MS like Perpetua it doesn't render the font, just a fallback font.

So I gathered I needed to install the fonts, but this is where I am getting stuck, I made a folder called `myfonts` inside `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`

Then I uploaded all my `.ttf` fonts from my Windows fonts folder.

I run `sudo fc-cache -vf`

```
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
....
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/myfonts: caching, new cache contents: 1083 fonts, 0 dirs
....
fc-cache: succeeded
```

I reboot Ubuntu and try generate the screenshot again but it does not use the fonts.

So reading around I thought perhaps I need to install the fonts into the X11 directory, so I do the same process inside the X11 directory but it still will not use the fonts

Does anyone have any idea what I could try next?

****Update****

I've done some more research, I done:

```
mkfontdir /path/to/fonts/folder
mkfontscale /path/to/fonts/folder
```

which has created a `.dir` and `.scale` file but this still does not use the fonts

Comment: There is legal issues also when use MS fonts outside.

Comment: This issue applies for free fonts too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this,

I had to do

```
mkfontdir /path/to/fonts/folder
mkfontscale /path/to/fonts/folder
```

and then

```
sudo fc-cache -vf
```